# Is there a drawback in using rxjs for readonly collection manipulation

Tags: linq, typescript, rxjs

I need to do a Min and Max operation on a array getting from server side.

I am new to rxjs extensions but those library is actually mean to observe changes on a collection, but in my case its just a ONE time calculation on a collection which is no further changed then until I do a server side refresh of the data.

I just want to use the right tool for the right job, thus I ask is it correct to use rxjs here or is that shooting with bombs on flys?

Or should I rather use a library like https://github.com/ENikS/LINQ

to get the Min/Max value of a collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a LINQ implementation [IxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/IxJS) that is developed and maintained by the same team that is developing RxJS. This might be the right tool for you.

However, you could go with RxJS as well. When using `Rx.Observable.from([1, 2, ...])` the execution is synchronous on subscription.

I would use IxJS however:

```
// An array of values.. (just creating some random ones here)
const values = [2, 4, 23, 1, 0, 34, 56, 2, 3, 45, 98, 6, 3];

// Create an enumerable from the array
const valEnum = Ix.Enumerable.fromArray(values);
const min = valEnum.min();
const max = valEnum.max();
```

Working example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9nvwxe2p/).

Comment: What would be the advantage of IxJS vs https://github.com/ENikS/LINQ Both are linq implementations, ah the ENikS Linq is in Typescript so I choose that!

Comment: I have not used ENikS Linq so I can not be sure. But IxJS has been stable for a few years now and it is being maintained by the same people at Microsoft that are developing RxJS. I have used many Linq implementations for javascript, and IxJS is the best one I have tried, There are excellent d.ts files for ixjs (i use typescript mostly myself).

Comment: ok ok then i try it, true its mature. Just have some problems loading it with systemJS...

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ENikS/LINQ uses all the latest language features and theoretically much faster than IxJS. Last edit on IxJS is 3 years old. (ECMA-262/6.0/) introduced few very important advancements and speed improvements.
It also has better compliance with standard LINQ API and can operate on any collection implementing iterables, including strings, maps, typed arrays, and etc. IxJS can only query array types.

Comment: I already use your library because I could export it to my app as its typescript :-), IxJS sucks in that matter.